# Does the electron configuration of an element increase or decrease speed of heat convection

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a question on whether or not the group of the metal affects the speed of heat transfer within an element. Is this irrelevant in thermodynamics or does the number of valence electrons have an impact on speed of heat convection.

Comment: Do you mean [heat conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction), which occurs in all materials, rather than [heat convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) which only really occurs in fluids.

Comment: Two points: (1) the number of electrons available for conduction in a metal doesn't change all that much (and they are the ones that conduct heat). (2) at normal human temperatures, phonons are the dominant thermal conduction mechanism.